# shell script handle an error from a command being excuted from echo

Tags: bash, shell

Hello I am new to `shell script` and I need to handle the `error` coming from a command being excuted inside `echo` like the following

```
echo -e "some internal command that I can't share \nq" | nc  localhost 10000
```

I want to say

```
if [[ there's no error ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
echo "YOUR SUPERSECRET COMMAND" | nc localhost 10000 | grep "Your expected error"
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "Do something useful with error"
else
   echo "Success"
fi
```

`grep` return 0 on matching and returns 1 when it doesn't find matching string.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but the status code $? is always 0 whether if there's a error or not

Comment: @Rifai_deve Try this.

Answer (score 0):

The shell variable `$?` will give you the exit code. So, you could do:

```
echo -e "some internal command that I can't share \nq" | nc  localhost 10000
rc=$?

if [[ $rc == 0 ]]; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

Or simply,

```
if echo -e "some internal command that I can't share \nq" | nc  localhost 10000; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but the status code $? is always 0 whether if there's a error or not

Comment: If `nc` always returns 0 then you can't do much about it. But in my few tries, it does return 1 on failures. So, how do you know it failed when it returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise way of doing it:

`internalcommand &>/dev/null 2>&1  && echo OK || echo FAILED`

If `internalcommand` succeeds OK will be printed to stdout, if it fails FAILED is printed.

Note tested on Bash v4